# Can't find what is the problem ? error: variable ar might not have been initialized . for(int x:a)System.out.println(x);

Tags: java

no error when if(flag==2) is replaced by if(true) or if statement is removed.

```java
class test{
    public static void main(String...arg) {
        int[] ar,b={1,2,3,4,5,6};
        int flag=2;
        if(flag == 2) ar = b; // no error when if(flag==2) is replaced by if(true).
        for(int x : ar) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Array `ar` is not initialised. Only `b` is. And only the hard-coded boolean `if(true)` *makes sure* it IS initialised

Comment: Local variables must be initialized before they are used. In your code, it is not guaranteed, that `ar` will be initialized. This is something that compiler won't let you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if construct i.e `if(flag == 2)` is not guaranteed to run as it is possible maybe the flag!=2 , so that leaves the array `ar uninitialized`.
As when you replace the if condition with `if (true){ }` then there is no compiler error seen. So you need to initialize Array with null so that you can escape the error but you will face `NullPointerException`.

```
    int[] ar = null,b = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int flag= 2;
    if (flag == 2) ar = b; 
    for(int x:ar) System.out.println(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because static code analysis doesn't look ***inside*** additional code blocks `if(true)` can be analyzed to eliminate the block. `b` is pointless. `flag` is pointless. Eliminate them and the problem goes away.

```
int[] ar = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
for (int x : ar) {
    System.out.println(x);
}
```